# Distance between a circle and a line

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Find the distance between the circle $(x-3)^2+(y+2)^2=4$ and the line $x + 2y = 9$.

Comment: Welcome to _Mathematica_.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with _Mathematica_ software.

Comment: Unless you indicate that you are using _Mathematica_ software to solve your problem this question is likely to be transferred to Math.SE.

Comment: The most straightforward, although not the most efficient answer to this problem would be direct conversion to minimizing implicit region distances: `MinValue[RegionDistance[ImplicitRegion[(x - 3)^2 + (y + 2)^2 == 4, {x, y}], {x1, y1}], {x1, y1} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[x + 2 y == 9, {x, y}], {x1, y1}, Reals]`

Comment: `Minimize[{Norm[{x1, y1} - {x2, y2}], (x1 - 3)^2 + (y1 + 2)^2 == 4, x2 + 2 y2 == 9}, {x1, y1, x2, y2}][[1]]`

Comment: It is easy to think of at least half a dozen methods to solve this in Mma, varying in their levels of "don't make me think". :)

Answer (score 3):

From a mathematical (as opposed to a Mathematica) perspective:

The center of the circle is at $P(3, -2)$, by inspection, and its radius is $2$.  The distance from $P$ to the line $x+2y = 9$ can be determined as follows.  We can rewrite the equation of that line as

$$
y = -\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{9}{2}
$$

Its slope is therefore $-\frac{1}{2}$, and the slope of a line that is perpendicular to that is $\frac{-1}{-\frac{1}{2}} = 2$.  A line of slope passing through $P$ has the equation

$$
y+2 = 2(x-3)
$$

or

$$
2x-y = 8
$$

By solving these two simultaneous equations, we arrive at the intersection point $(5, 2)$.  This point has a distance $\sqrt{(5-3)^2+[2-(-2)]^2} = \sqrt{20} = 2\sqrt{5}$ from $P$.  Since the circle has a radius of $2$, the distance between the circle and the line is $2\sqrt{5}-2$.

Drawing out a rough diagram of the situation should make this clearer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Distance from circle $(x-3)^2+(y+2)^2=4$ to line $x + 2y = 9$

The distance from the circle
$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$ 
to the line 
$ax + by + c=0$

is the distance from the line to the center of the circle minus 
the radius of the circle:

$\dfrac{|ax_0 + by_0 + c|}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} - r$

In this case

$\dfrac{|1(3) + 2(-2) - 9|}{\sqrt{1^2 + 2^2}} - 2 = 2\sqrt 5 - 2$

Answer (score 0):

As [Kirma suggested in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105470/distance-between-a-circle-and-a-line#comment286363_105470), you can use the geometric region calculation capabilities built-in to newer versions of *Mathematica*.

In practice, we ask *Mathematica* to derive an expression for the distance between a region and an arbitrary $(x_1,y_1)$ point (`RegionDistance)`.

Then we minimize this function and report the value of this distance function at this minimum using `MinValue`.

However, from the standpoint of performance it is very important to pick the regions carefully. In particular, the expression obtained for the generic distance *from a line* is much more manageable and easier to minimize than the generic distance from a circle, so it is much more convenient to use the former (i.e. the choice to that suggested by Kirma):

```
MinValue[
 RegionDistance[ImplicitRegion[x + 2 y == 9, {x, y}], {x1, y1}],
 {x1, y1} ∈ ImplicitRegion[(x - 3)^2 + (y + 2)^2 == 4, {x, y}]
]

(* Out: Sqrt[1/5 (120 - 40 Sqrt[5])] *)
```

---

In the case shown above, the answer is obtained essentially instantaneously. Using the opposite choice of regions yields the same result (after simplification) but it takes *much* longer:

```
MinValue[
   RegionDistance[ImplicitRegion[(x - 3)^2 + (y + 2)^2 == 4, {x, y}], {x1, y1}],
   {x1, y1} ∈ ImplicitRegion[x + 2 y == 9, {x, y}]
]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {45.2216, Null} *)
```

Comment: Ha! A good point about which region to use inside `RegionDistance`.